# Reconfigure power button to run batchfile on short press

Tags: windows-8.1

So i have a laptop windows 8.1 and i frequently stream movies and TV shows to my TV via chromecast or HDMI port so i created a batch file to turn my screen off and lock the computer that part so far works just fine except for the fact that whenever i run the script i have to alt tab out to my desktop so as it goes not a huge problem but one i would like to fix i would preferably like to change it so a short press of the power button on my laptop runs the script either by changing a setting in windows or via a 3rd party program and i do not want the short press to run the standard shut down routines but if at all possible would like the long press reboot function to remain intact or even a secondary way to do what is done by the batch program any help would be appreciated

Comment: that might not be right as it is defintely technically possible. If it isn't on windows it is a purely artificial restriction that may be worked around using 3rd party tools

Answer (score -1):

You can only do three things with the power button: shutdown, hibernate/sleep, or nothing.

You could connect up a separate button via USB and have AutoHotkey or something else run your batch file though.